# It seems like each View Controller is creating a unique instance of my struct - which I don't want?

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I'm creating an app in Swift 2.0 xCode7 using the Tabbed-Application template, with each screen having a separate ViewController.  I have a struct to manage a variable I want to be accessed by all view controllers.  I created the instance of the struct in the first view controller.  I'm able to access the struct data and methods in the other views, but if update the data in one view, it doesn't change for all... It's acting as if each View Controller is creating its own instance on its own.  I don't want that.  I want each ViewController to share the same updated data in the struct.  Does this mean that I should be creating a Singleton Pattern?  Or, something else?  I'm quite new at this, so thanks for your patience.

Comment: Yes, you have to implement Singleton class.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how exactly you access the structure but it might be that you only need to change `struct` to `class` because structs are value types so if you assign it or pass into a method it is copied whereas an instance of a class will avoid copying

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't give me any code, this is just my guess.

Structs are different from classes. The former stores *values* and the latter stores *references*. Let's look at this code:

```
var obj = SomethingCool()
obj.somethingCooler = 20
var obj2 = obj
obj2.somethingCooler = 10
```

If `SomethingCool` were a struct, `obj.somethingCooler` would still be 20 but `obj2.somethingCooler` would be 10. On the other hand, if `SomethingCool` were a class, both `obj.somethingCooler` and `obj2.somethingCooler` would be 20.

This is because the third line. The third line is VERY important. If `SomethingCool` were a struct, the values stored in `obj` will be *copied* to `obj2`. i.e. **Two set of independent values would be created.** If it were a class, the object that `obj` will also be referenced by `obj2`. i.e. **There would still be just one object**.

Now that you know the difference, I can tell you that you must have done something like the third line in your view controllers, haven't you?

To solve this problem, you can change from a struct to a class. Or you can create something like this:

```
public class SomeName {
    static var myData: SomeTypeOfStruct {
        return something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are so hellbent on keeping it as a struct you could do something that swift actually helps u out with.....AppDelegate!

The appdelegate.swift is a single instance object for any application. So in case you want to save a value that you need to access throughout the application or update throughtout the application, you might want to use AppDelegate.

E.g.
In FirstViewController.swift set the AppDelegate variable that you want to reflect on the remaining screens:

```
(UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).commonVariableName = NewValueYouWant;
```

In the SecondViewController.swift, take up that value from the AppDelegate

```
var updatedValue = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).commonVariableName;
```

Again...as @Sweeper said, you can always switch to class which is more reliable and used to achieve something like this.

Comment: No, do not use the app delegate for this. It is not the place to put all of your "global" values.

Comment: Well...If u read my first line you will understand what I mean..
"If you are so hellbent on keeping it as a struct...."

One needs to use classes to achieve something like this....

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is a struct, a class, or a simple value. Do not use the app delegate as a place to store such data.

Answer (score 0):

> It's acting as if each View Controller is creating its own instance on
>   its own.

It's all explained in Apple's [Swift guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82):

Structs:

```
struct Dog {
    var name: String
}

var d1 = Dog(name: "Rover")
var d2 = d1
d2.name = "Sally"

print(d1.name)
print(d2.name)

--output:--
Rover
Sally
```

Classes:

```
class Cat {
    var name: String = ""
}

var c1 = Cat()
c1.name = "Kitty"
var c2 = c1
c2.name = "Gerald"
print(c1.name)
print(c2.name)

--output:--
Gerald
Gerald
```

See the difference?

Comment: That was it!  Thanks.  I've converted my struct to a class and now all four View Controllers are working with the data as I intended.